# Extract portion of text in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-4.5

I need to extract of subset of a String using a pair of markers that would be contained within it.  For example, given the following String:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   `<!--extract-->`**Sed nec luctus magna, ac tincidunt metus. Maecenas
>   sodales iaculis ipsum sed blandit.**`<!--/extract-->` Quisque tincidunt
>   nulla sapien, non faucibus turpis aliquam at.

How can I extract everything in between  and  (but not the tags themselves)?  The String will be different lengths every time, but will always contain the markers.

I've been messing with `String.SubString()` but am struggling to reliably calculate the start/end indexes.  Note that the start/end markers will always have specific values to allow them to be located.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it easier to `Substring` twice when trimming from both sides of a desired string

```
string myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <!--extract-->Sed nec luctus magna, ac tincidunt metus. Maecenas sodales iaculis ipsum sed blandit.<!--/extract--> Quisque tincidunt nulla sapien, non faucibus turpis aliquam at.";
myString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("<!--extract-->") + "<!--extract-->".Length);
myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf("<!--/extract-->"));
```

Or, to do the same in one call (uglier)

```
string myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <!--extract-->Sed nec luctus magna, ac tincidunt metus. Maecenas sodales iaculis ipsum sed blandit.<!--/extract--> Quisque tincidunt nulla sapien, non faucibus turpis aliquam at.";
myString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("<!--extract-->") + "<!--extract-->".Length, myString.IndexOf("<!--/extract-->") - myString.IndexOf("<!--extract-->") - "<!--extract-->".Length);
```

Comment: Great thanks.  Super quick response and right on the money!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you achive your requirement

```
    string s="adipiscing elit.<!--extract-->Sed nec luct<!--/extract-->"
    string p = "<!--extract-->";
    string q = "<!--/extract-->";
    int a = s.IndexOf("<!--extract-->");

    int b = s.IndexOf("<!--/extract-->");
    string result= s.Substring(a + p.Length, b - (a + p.Length));
```